# How to send json data to my table in mysql database with nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, excel

I know this is a general question, but I have the following code in my app.js

```
app.post('/data', (req, res) =>{
    const file = req.files.filename;
    const nose = [];
    const filename = file.name;
    file.mv('./excel/'+filename, (err)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else{
            const result = importExcel({
                sourceFile: './excel/'+filename,
                header: {rows:1},
                columnToKey :{A:'Dimension', B:'Category', C:'Subcategory',D:'Factor', E:'Context', F:'Date',G:'Indicator', H:'Formula',I:'FoundValue'},
                sheets:['data']

            })
            for(var i=0; result.data.length > i; i++){
                nose.push(result.data[i].Dimension,
                            result.data[i].Category)
            }
            res.send(nose)
            console.log(nose+' = Total data '+nose.length);
        }
    })
    })
```

Here is my data.ejs in the part of the button for sending data

```
 <form action="/data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div style="float:right">
            <input style="margin-top:6%;" class="btn btn-light" type="file" name="filename"> 
            <button style="float:right" type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-4"><i class="fa-solid fa-file-import"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="footer" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px!important;">
```

Right now it looks visually like this; [image]

And my data is displayed like this;
[image]

Which is fine, because that's what my excel looks like;
[image]

Context: I need to send that .json data in app.js to my MySQL database using Nodejs but I don't know how to send that data to my database table, I've seen that they use multer,sequelize, etc. I don't know if that's the way or there are easier ways to understand for a newbie like me.

I also have an app. get, like this;

```
app.get('/data', (req, res) =>{
    connection.query('SELECT c.data_id, d.dimension_name, cc.category_name, s.subcategory_name, f.factor_name,f.factor_description,c.date_creation_data, c.Indicator,ff.formula_name FROM data_load c INNER JOIN dimensions d ON c.dimension_id = d. id_dimensions INNER JOIN categories cc ON c.id_categories = cc.id_categories INNER JOIN subcategory s ON c.id_subcategories = s.id_subcategories INNER JOIN factors f ON c.id_factor = f.id_factor INNER JOIN formulas ff ON c.id_formula = ff.id_formula;',
    function(error, results){
        if(error){
            console.log(error)
        } else{
            res.render('./data', {
                results:results
            })
        }
    })
    
})
```

My table, too, as you noticed in app.get has several INNER JOIN, so this is my table at present;
[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `carga_datos` (
  `id_datos` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_dimensiones` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_categorias` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_subcategorias` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_factor` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_creacion_data` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `Indicador` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_formula` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

ALTER TABLE `carga_datos`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_datos`),
  ADD KEY `id_dimensiones` (`id_dimensiones`),
  ADD KEY `id_categorias` (`id_categorias`),
  ADD KEY `id_subcategorias` (`id_subcategorias`),
  ADD KEY `id_factor` (`id_factor`),
  ADD KEY `id_formula` (`id_formula`);

ALTER TABLE `carga_datos`
  MODIFY `id_datos` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

ALTER TABLE `carga_datos`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `carga_datos_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_dimensiones`) REFERENCES `dimensiones` (`id_dimensiones`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `carga_datos_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_categorias`) REFERENCES `categorias` (`id_categorias`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `carga_datos_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_subcategorias`) REFERENCES `subcategoria` (`id_subcategorias`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `carga_datos_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`id_factor`) REFERENCES `factores` (`id_factor`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `carga_datos_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`id_formula`) REFERENCES `formulas` (`id_formula`);
COMMIT;
```

Please help, I don't know what to do,

Thanks in advance :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using sequelize for your data models. This example should get you on your way.

You create and update tables via migrations, then run them via your console:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('carga_datos', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      id_datos: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      id_dimensiones: {
        allowNull: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      id_categorias: {
        allowNull: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      id_subcategorias: {
        allowNull: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    })
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('carga_datos');
  }
};
```

You will define your model schemas like this:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    var carga_datos = sequelize.define('carga_datos', {
        id: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        id_datos: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        id_dimensiones: {
            allowNull: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        id_categorias: {
            allowNull: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        id_subcategorias: {
            allowNull: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        createdAt: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: DataTypes.DATE
        },
        updatedAt: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: DataTypes.DATE
        }
    })
    carga_datos.associate = function (models) {

    }
    return carga_datos;
}
```

When you want to create a new entry in your database, you will use:

```
const datos = await carga_datos.create({
    id_datos: req.body.id_datos,
    id_dimensiones: req.body.id_dimensiones
})
```

Pay attention to the types when writing models and migrations, they may get confused. Good luck!